# Вставка флеш на сайте

Tags: flash

Здравствуйте, сделал логотип на флеш. Имею файл `logo.swf`. Как внедрить его в шаблон?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
<object  width="100" height="22">
  <param name="movie" value="logo.swf" />
  <param name="quality" value="high" />
  <embed src="logo.swf" quality="high"  width="100" height="22"></embed>
</object>
```